# 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Tags: r

I am creating a function that read a hospital's dataset for the USA, gets two arguments the state and the outcome(heart attack for example), and return the name of the hospital that has the lowest death in the case of that prespecified outcome so my function was.

```
best <- function(state, outcome){
        outcomedata <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv")
        outcomedata <- outcomedata[ , c(2,7,11,17,23)]
        outcomedata[,c(3,4,5)] <- as.numeric(outcomedata[ ,c(3,4,5)])
        colnames(outcomedata) <- c("Hospital", "State", "heartattack", "hf", "pneumonia")
        outcomedata$heartattack <- as.numeric(outcomedata$heartattack)
        outcomedata$hf <- as.numeric(outcomedata$hf)
        outcomedata$pneumonia <- as.numeric(outcomedata$pneumonia)
        outcomedata <- outcomedata[outcomedata$State == state, ]
        deathoutcomes <- c("heart attack", "heart failure", "pneumonia")
       
        if(!(state %in% outcomedata[['State']]) | !(outcome %in% deathoutcomes)){
            print("error")
        } else{
if(outcome == "heart attack"){
 lowestdeathheartattack <- outcomedata[outcomedata$heartattack == min(outcomedata$heartattack), ]
 lowestdeathheartattack <- lowestdeathheartattack[order(lowestdeathheartattack$Hospital), ]
 print(lowestdeathheartattack)
} else if(outcome == "heart failure"){
  lowestdeathheartf <- outcomedata[outcomedata$hf == min(outcomedata$hf), ]
  lowestdeathheartf <- lowestdeathheartf[order(lowestdeathheartf$Hospital), ]
  print(lowestdeathheartf)
} else if(outcome == "pneumonia"){
  lowestpneumoniadf <- outcomedata[outcomedata$pneumonia == min(outcomedata$pneumonia), ]
  lowestpneumoniadf <- lowestpneumoniadf[order(lowestpneumoniadf$Hospital), ]
  print(lowestpneumoniadf) }}}
```

I will get the error

```
best("NY", "heart failure")
Error in best("NY", "heart failure") : 
  'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

I tried using lapply I got he same problem.

```
outcomedata[,c(3,4,5)] <- lapply(outcomedata[ ,c(3,4,5)], as.numeric)
```

Comment: the second way is correct. you get the same error if you replace `outcomedata[,c(3,4,5)] <- as.numeric(outcomedata[ ,c(3,4,5)])` with that?

Comment: Can you share a sample of your data so we could more easily help?

Comment: @rawr Thanks for your reply, yes I get the same error.

Comment: @jpsmith Thanks for your reply, I have uploaded the data if you want to take a look

Comment: @jpsmith
https://www.dropbox.com/s/tn74ig2r4hugw4g/outcome-of-care-measures.csv?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will work, and simplify your code. First, you should put all of the following data manipulation code outside of your function (I imported your original data as `df`):

```
outcomedata <- df[ , c(2,7,11,17,23)]
outcomedata[3:5] <- lapply(outcomedata[3:5], as.numeric)
colnames(outcomedata) <- c("Hospital", "State", "heartattack", "hf", "pneumonia")
```

Note all the other code was unnecessary, and your original error was resolved by `outcomedata[3:5] <- lapply(outcomedata[3:5], as.numeric)`, though more problems persisted in your function.

You can run the following function to find the minimum death in the case of that prespecified outcome within a desired state:

### dplyr

```
dplyr_function <- function(state_want, outcome){
  outcomedata %>% 
    filter(State == state_want) %>% 
    slice_min({{outcome}}) %>% 
    select(c(Hospital, State,{{outcome}}))
}
```

For instance, `dplyr_function("GA", heartattack)` returns:

```
#                  Hospital State heartattack
#1 STEPHENS COUNTY HOSPITAL    GA        12.9
```

Also note that something like this:

```
outcomedata %>% 
  group_by(State) %>% 
  slice_min(hf) %>% 
  select(c(Hospital, State,hf))
```

Will return a data set with the minimum of `hf` in every state. Not sure if this would be easier for your application.

### Base R

In base R, you can use `which.min()`:

```
baseRfunction <- function(state_want, outcome){
  a <- outcomedata[outcomedata$State == state_want,]
  a[which.min(a[,outcome]), c("Hospital","State",outcome)]
}
```

Where `baseRfunction("GA", "heartattack")` returns:

```
#                    Hospital State heartattack 
#931 STEPHENS COUNTY HOSPITAL    GA        12.9
```

Note that in this function, both inputs are in quotations ("").

Comment: Thanks a lot, is it possible to be done without dplyr?

Comment: Yep sure can - see edit

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me make better code, I am a medical doctor started my public health path recently and I felt with love with data science. I hope to reach your level with coding one day. Thanks a lot

Comment: when I excute the function this error appears and all values are NA, I kept my old code and I just changed the data type tranformation part. why is that happening? 
'Warning messages:
1: In lapply(outcomedata[3:5], as.numeric) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In lapply(outcomedata[3:5], as.numeric) : NAs introduced by coercion
3: In lapply(outcomedata[3:5], as.numeric) : NAs introduced by coercion'

Comment: Oh I think because I put the manipulation inside the function, but this is a part of assignment and it requires the manipulation to be inside the function.